# Detecting Spywares

Tags: monitoring, spyware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

I feel like my computer is being monitored by someone. I am terrified by seeing space character being written while I was typing something. My 2 computer showed this same sign. At first I thought it can be space bar which is faulty but then how can fault be occurred on 2 computers at the same time?

I'm not sure if it's really being monitored and who's after it. Is there a way I can find it out?

Comment: Related: [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/q/100360/108226)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see is to see if the problem exists when your internet is disconnected. Your computer can't be controlled when it is disconnected from the internet.

Of course it could have some [Malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware). I would recommend refrenceing the [Computer is infected by virus or malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) article.

Comment: This occurred sometimes and not always. I had thought of disconnecting it to internet.